# how to save parameter values in .property file?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, url, servlets

how to save values of parameter with its value like key value pair in .properties file in jsp

**For Eg.**
url :
http://www.xyz.com/login.jsp?**fname=harry&lname=potter&occupation=actor**

.property file must look like this

**fname=harry 

lname=potter

occupation=actor**

is it possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'is it possible'? What's wrong with what you suggest?

Comment: @bmorris591 i have googled but not finding what i want

Comment: @bmorris591 not tried yet but want to know 1st is it possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Why wouldn't it be? Voting to close. That's not the job of a JSP though. A servlet should do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
final String urlString = "http://www.xyz.com/login.jsp?fname=harry&lname=potter&occupation=actor";
final URL url;
try {
    url = new URL(urlString);
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
final Properties properties = new Properties();
for (final String param : url.getQuery().split("\\&")) {
    final String[] splitParam = param.split("=");
    properties.setProperty(splitParam[0], splitParam[1]);
}
for (final String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    System.out.println("Key " + key + " has value " + properties.getProperty(key) + ".");
}
final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("My File"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
try {
    properties.store(fileOutputStream, "Properties from URL '" +urlString + "'.");
} catch(IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
} finally {
    try {
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

}
```

This will parse the URL and put the params into a `Properties` object, it will then write it to a file.

Note that if you have any repeated keys in your URL string they will be overwritten so this method will not work.  In that case you may want to take a look at [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Check `java.util.Properties.store(OutputStream, String)` and `java.util.Properties.store(Writer, String)`(Java 1.6)